# how does Array#map have parameter to do something like this?

Tags: ruby

```
def double(a)
 a*2
end

method_object = method(:double)
```

and here's my question, how does this code:

```
[1,3,5,6].map(&method_object)
```

achieve the same result of

```
[1,3,5,6].map {|x| method_object.call(x)}
```

in the Ruby document, the Array#map only can have block, not normal parameter

```
ary.collect {|item| block } → new_ary ary.map {|item| block } → new_ary ary.collect → an_enumerator ary.map → an_enumerator
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, the ampersand `&` is used to "pack / unpack" a method object to a block, so the effect is more-less the same as if you passed the block.

You can "get" the block that has been passed to your method by:

```
def method_with_block(&foo)
  # do something here
  foo.call
  # do something else
end
```

This will be similar to calling `yield` and not declaring `&foo` as parameter. I think binding might differ between the two approaches, but in most cases the effect is what you would expect (if I am mistaken, please correct).

Of course, the ampersand works the other way around - if a method expects a block and you have a proc object, you can simply prepend it with `&`, just as you wrote. To be more precise, `&` calls `to_proc` method of the passed object (Rails uses this in a manner similar to [described in this entry about to_proc](http://www.dan-manges.com/blog/29).

I hope that this answers some of your doubts. In case there is a mistake in what I wrote, feel free to correct it.

Readings you might find useful:

- [Programming Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/), essential book
- [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Method_Calls#Understanding_blocks.2C_Procs_and_methods) contains a section about this topic
- [This simple blog entry](http://yaronwalfish.com/all-about-the-ruby-ampersand-operator-in-a-function-call/) shows an example

Answer (score 0):

you can extend class integer:

```
class Integer
  def double
    self*2
  end
end

[1,2,3,4].map(&:double)
[
    [0] 2,
    [1] 4,
    [2] 6,
    [3] 8
]
```